# Which Package has net_tstamp.h?

Tags: linux-networking, packages, centos6.2

I attempted to compile the source code here: http://os1a.cs.columbia.edu/lxr/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c?a=x86;v=2.6.32

However, I got a compiler error: error: linux/net_tstamp.h: No such file or directory

I looked at /usr/include/linux, and indeed I don't have that file.

Then, I searched online for awhile but I can't find which package has that file.

I am on CentOS 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**`yum provides *linux/net_tstamp.h`**

```
kernel-debug-devel-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the debug kernel
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64.debug/include/linux/net_tstamp.h



kernel-devel-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/include/linux/net_tstamp.h



kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/linux/net_tstamp.h
```

Comment: Thanks! (unfortunately I don't have the ability to vote up)